# yarn installs different packages on different machines

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have some node project that uses yarn as the package manager, I have a windows 10 laptop and windows 10 PC, I'm able to install all the packages using yarn, but when trying to run the project it works on the laptop but fails on the PC(seems like some packages are not fully installed or something, but the yarn install does finish seemingly successfully).

I tried to match some parameters like node version, msvs version, windows SDK version, etc, but I just can't think of anything else that would cause this to happen.

I can't really share the project as it's not open source, but I'm just not sure about what could actually cause this to happen.

When installing the packages, on the PC it says that it installs 133073 files(or dependency linking), while on the laptop it says that it installs 134040 files. I believe this is where the difference is, also, if I run yarn install on the laptop and then just move the files to the PC, it works properly, I do need to get it working on the PC though.

Any advices or troubleshooting ideas would be very useful, thanks.